# JAVAFX - Datepicker print day of week

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

I'm trying to use datepicker in JavaFX to print/get the day of the week ex. Mon or Tue etc based on the users choice on the calendar.

At the moment I can only retrieve the date eg.

```
LocalDate ld = dpBookingDate.getValue();
    System.out.println(ld.toString());
```

Which prints the date, so something like 12/5/17 which is the format I'm currently not trying to use.

But I just want to get the name of the day. How do I do this?

Comment: `System.out.println(ld.getDayOfWeek())` would seem to be a reasonable candidate.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, You can use the following code

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EE").format(date);
```